# Is it possible to create a model from view values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `form` with complex functionality (drag-and-drop, deleting groups of elements, adding groups of elements) that I'd like to treat with Angular.
The form is already rendered with original values are set.

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input ng-model="rule[0].rule" value="bar">
        <select ng-model="rule[0].value">
            <option>A</option>
            <option selected>B</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input ng-model="rule[1].rule" value="foo">
        <select ng-model="rule[1].value">
            <option selected>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

The problem is that Angular nullifies these values and creates no `rule` array in `$scope`. What I want is to create array of objects `rule` from the values of my template.

I do understand that my demand violates MVC pattern in the way that data is provieded by template. Nevertheless, I would like to avoid excessive data parcing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: no, it is not possible.

You need to define $scope.rule as an array in your controller before you can start using it in your view.

```
$scope.rule = [];
```

In the view you will not be able to add anything to your `$scope`...

Comment: apparently I can't

Answer (score 0):

Your form have two very similar peaces of code, and probably you will put more. It is better to host all representation in the controller, and just build from it. Let me show example for you.

View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in options">
    <input ng-model="item.rule">
    <select ng-model="item.value">
      <option ng-repeat="option in item.options" ng-value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
    <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.options = [{
    value: 'B',
    rule: 'foo',
    options: ['A', 'B']
  }, {
    value: 2,
    rule: 'bar',
    options: [1, 2]
  }];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzadc03v/

Hope it will help you!